# Can't drag maximized windows from the panel like i could in the beta

Tags: unity, panel

While in beta i could just drag the panel (in unity) and the maximized windows would be restored to normal size. Now i can only drag it using the alt key . 
Is this a design choice to make us use the buttons on the left or did i just disable something by mistake? Is there any way to get the previous behavior back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be working in my laptop. Try this once:

1. Open up CompizConfig Settings Manager (install the package `ccsm` if you don't already have it).
2. Scroll down to the "Window Management" section and open the "Grid" plugin by clicking it.
   [image: ccsm grid plugin location]
3. Navigate to the "Edges" tab and expand the "Resize Actions" section.
4. Ensure that the settings "Snapoff maximized windows" and "Snap windows back to original size" are checked. Also ensure that the "Grid" plugin itself is enabled :).
   [image]